# Convert wchar_t to char

Tags: c++

I was wondering is it safe to do so?

```
wchar_t wide = /* something */;
assert(wide >= 0 && wide < 256 &&);
char myChar = static_cast<char>(wide);
```

If I am pretty sure the wide char will fall within ASCII range.

Comment: Note that the ASCII range is strictly 0..127, not 0..255 as the test implies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`assert` is for ensuring that something is true in a debug mode, without it having any effect in a release build. Better to use an `if` statement and have an alternate plan for characters that are outside the range, unless the only way to get characters outside the range is through a program bug.

Also, depending on your character encoding, you might find a difference between the Unicode characters 0x80 through 0xff and their `char` version.

Answer (score 37):

Why not just use a library routine [`wcstombs`](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/wcstom.html).

Comment: That is for string. I just want to convert a single char.

Comment: @Igor Zevaka, I just tested that and found it be wrong. Did you correct the mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

You are looking for [`wctomb()`](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/wctomb.html): it's in the ANSI standard, so you can count on it. It works even when the `wchar_t` uses a code above 255. You almost certainly do not want to use it.

---

`wchar_t` *is* an integral type, so your compiler won't complain if you actually do:

```
char x = (char)wc;
```

but *because* it's an integral type, there's absolutely no reason to do this. If you accidentally read [Herbert Schildt's C: The Complete Reference](http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html), or **any** C book based on it, then you're completely and grossly misinformed. *Characters* should be of type `int` *or better*. That means you should be writing this:

```
int x = getchar();
```

and not this:

```
char x = getchar(); /* <- WRONG! */
```

As far as integral types go, `char` is worthless. You shouldn't make functions that take parameters of type `char`, and you should not create temporary variables of type `char`, and the same advice goes for `wchar_t` as well.

`char*` may be a convenient typedef for a character string, but it is a novice mistake to think of this as an "array of characters" or a "pointer to an array of characters" - despite what the [cdecl](http://pastebin.com/k7PXTmJn) tool says. Treating it as an actual array of characters with nonsense like this:

```
for(int i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {
  wchar_t wc = s[i];
  char c = doit(wc);
  out[i] = c;
}
```

is absurdly wrong. It will *not* do what you want; it *will* break in subtle and serious ways, behave differently on different platforms, and you *will most certainly* confuse the hell out of your users. If you see this, you are trying to reimplement [`wctombs()`](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/wcstom.html) which is part of ANSI C already, **but it's still wrong**.

You're *really* looking for [`iconv()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.3.html), which converts a character string from one encoding (even if it's packed into a `wchar_t` array), into a character string of another encoding.

Now go read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), to learn what's wrong with iconv.

Comment: I don't think the opening statement of this answer is justified by the question as posed.  It looks to me like he's asking about truncating a 16-bit value to an 8-bit value; nowhere does he ask about preserving semantics.

Comment: Furthermore, the `char` value he's processing might be `char` because it came from, say, `cin.getline()` which acts on `char[]`.

Comment: Correct but vain, the _`char` is wothless_ is a very arguable statement.

Answer (score 10):

**An easy way is :**

```
        wstring your_wchar_in_ws(<your wchar>);
        string your_wchar_in_str(your_wchar_in_ws.begin(), your_wchar_in_ws.end());
        char* your_wchar_in_char =  your_wchar_in_str.c_str();
```

I'm using this method for years :)

Comment: But does it fail or generate garbage when there are non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 7):

A short function I wrote a while back to pack a wchar_t array into a char array.  Characters that aren't on the ANSI code page (0-127) are replaced by '?' characters, and it handles surrogate pairs correctly.

```
size_t to_narrow(const wchar_t * src, char * dest, size_t dest_len){
  size_t i;
  wchar_t code;

  i = 0;

  while (src[i] != '\0' && i < (dest_len - 1)){
    code = src[i];
    if (code < 128)
      dest[i] = char(code);
    else{
      dest[i] = '?';
      if (code >= 0xD800 && code <= 0xD8FF)
        // lead surrogate, skip the next code unit, which is the trail
        i++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  dest[i] = '\0';

  return i - 1;

}
```

Comment: What is `w` supposed to be ? Isn't it supposed to be `src` ?

Comment: it should be src.  The code isn't exactly what I have originally, and I missed that instance when refactoring.

Comment: @cvanbrederode per this article: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2274038&seqNum=10 I think you want to check the ranges from 0xD800 through 0xDBFF. "B" in "DBFF" rather than an "8".

Answer (score 3):

Technically, '`char`' could have the same range as either '`signed char`' or '`unsigned char`'.  For the unsigned characters, your range is correct; theoretically, for signed characters, your condition is wrong.  In practice, very few compilers will object - and the result will be the same.

Nitpick: the last `&&` in the `assert` is a syntax error.

Whether the assertion is appropriate depends on whether you can afford to crash when the code gets to the customer, and what you could or should do if the assertion condition is violated but the assertion is not compiled into the code.  For debug work, it seems fine, but you might want an active test after it for run-time checking too.

Comment: 'char' and 'signed char' are synonymous.

Comment: @cvanbrederode: That is not what the standard says.  §6.2.5 **Types** ¶15 says: _The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the character types. The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.45)_ Footnote 45 says: _`CHAR_MIN`, defined in `<limits.h>`, will have one of the values 0 or `SCHAR_MIN`, and this can be
used to distinguish the two options. Irrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the
other two and is not compatible with either._

Comment: I quoted the C11 standard — ISO/IEC 9899:2011.  I see this is actually a C++ question. In the old C++11 standard — ISO/IEC 14882:2011, §3.9.1 **Fundamental types** ¶1 says: _It is implementation-defined
whether a char object can hold negative values. Characters can be explicitly declared unsigned or signed.
Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types. A char, a signed char, and an
unsigned char occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements (3.11); that
is, they have the same object representation._ _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ and it also says: _In any particular implementation,
a plain `char` object can take on either the same values as a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`;
which one is implementation-defined._ I don't think there's any material change in the C++14 standard. The net result is the same as the C standard quote — plain `char` is the same as either `unsigned char` or `signed char` and it is up to the implementation to decide which is used.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of doing it, remember to use free() on the result.

```
char* wchar_to_char(const wchar_t* pwchar)
{
    // get the number of characters in the string.
    int currentCharIndex = 0;
    char currentChar = pwchar[currentCharIndex];

    while (currentChar != '\0')
    {
        currentCharIndex++;
        currentChar = pwchar[currentCharIndex];
    }

    const int charCount = currentCharIndex + 1;

    // allocate a new block of memory size char (1 byte) instead of wide char (2 bytes)
    char* filePathC = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * charCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
    {
        // convert to char (1 byte)
        char character = pwchar[i];

        *filePathC = character;

        filePathC += sizeof(char);

    }
    filePathC += '\0';

    filePathC -= (sizeof(char) * charCount);

    return filePathC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one could also convert wchar_t --> wstring  --> string --> char

```
wchar_t wide;
wstring wstrValue;
wstrValue[0] = wide

string strValue;
strValue.assign(wstrValue.begin(), wstrValue.end());  // convert wstring to string

char char_value = strValue[0];
```

Comment: This code could fail occasionally because you're actually replacing zero-character in `wstrValue` with another one (refer to line `wstrValue[0] = wide`). The string will have wrong length (if the implementation caches it) and can look like a garbage leading to an access violation when accessing it later.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. `int(wchar_t(255)) == int(char(255))` of course, but that just means they have the same int value. They may not represent the same characters.

You would see such a discrepancy in the majority of Windows PCs, even. For instance, on Windows Code page 1250, `char(0xFF)` is the same character as `wchar_t(0x02D9)` (dot above), not `wchar_t(0x00FF)` (small y with diaeresis).

Note that it does not even hold for the ASCII range, as C++ doesn't even require ASCII. On IBM systems in particular you may see that `'A' != 65`