# C++ method to check if a File is on Disk wchar_t

Tags: c++, filesystems

I wanted a means of checking is a file exists on the disk based on wchar_t * path.
A ready to use method is available on SO but for char * path. Is there a variant for wchar_t * without using boost.

Comment: The file system does not really care about char or wchar_t filename. This is only a string representation in your code for a filename. If the file API you are using, needs a char* and you only have a wchar_t*, which contains the filename, you just need to concert this string in your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019977/convert-wchar-t-to-char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loot at this example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool check_if_file_exists(std::wstring path)
{
    std::ifstream ff(path.c_str());
    return ff.is_open();
}
```

But this is windows only, since std::ifstream(wchar_t*) is MSVC extension.