# cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}

Tags: c++, unicode, mingw

I have a .cpp file which is a Tetris game code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

const vector<vector<wstring>> tetromino = {
    // I
    {
        L"....XX......XX......XX......XX..", //   0 deg
        L"................XXXXXXXX........", //  90 deg
        L"..XX......XX......XX......XX....", // 180 deg
        L"........XXXXXXXX................"  // 270 deg
    },

    // J
    {
        L"....XX......XX....XXXX..........",
        L"..........XX......XXXXXX........",
        L"..........XXXX....XX......XX....",
        L"........XXXXXX......XX.........."
    },

    // L
    {
        L"..XX......XX......XXXX..........",
        L"..........XXXXXX..XX............",
        L"..........XXXX......XX......XX..",
        L"............XX..XXXXXX.........."
    },

    // O
    {
        L"..........XXXX....XXXX..........",
        L"..........XXXX....XXXX..........",
        L"..........XXXX....XXXX..........",
        L"..........XXXX....XXXX.........."
    },

    // S
    {
        L"..XX......XXXX......XX..........",
        L"............XXXX..XXXX..........",
        L"..........XX......XXXX......XX..",
        L"..........XXXX..XXXX............"
    },

    // T
    {
        L"..XX......XXXX....XX............",
        L"..........XXXXXX....XX..........",
        L"............XX....XXXX......XX..",
        L"..........XX....XXXXXX.........."
    },

    // Z
    {
        L"....XX....XXXX....XX............",
        L"..........XXXX......XXXX........",
        L"............XX....XXXX....XX....",
        L"........XXXX......XXXX.........."
    }
};

const int nScreenWidth = 39;
const int nScreenHeight = 21;

const int nBoardWidth = 22;
const int nBoardHeight = 21;

const wstring detail = L" ▓█░╚╝║═";

int random(int nMin, int nMax)
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(nMin, nMax);

    auto num = uni(rng);
    return num;
}

void Configure()
{
    system("MODE 39, 22");
    system("color 89");

    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX csbiex;
    csbiex.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsoleOutput, &csbiex);
    csbiex.ColorTable[0] = RGB(0, 188, 212);
    csbiex.ColorTable[1] = RGB(63, 81, 181);
    csbiex.ColorTable[2] = RGB(255, 87, 34);
    csbiex.ColorTable[3] = RGB(255, 235, 59);
    csbiex.ColorTable[4] = RGB(76, 175, 80);
    csbiex.ColorTable[5] = RGB(156, 39, 176);
    csbiex.ColorTable[6] = RGB(237, 28, 36);
    csbiex.ColorTable[7] = RGB(242, 242, 242);
    csbiex.ColorTable[8] = RGB(248, 248, 248);
    csbiex.ColorTable[9] = RGB(20, 20, 20);

    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsoleOutput, &csbiex);
}

void Frame(wchar_t*& wcBuffer, wstring wsCaption, int nWidth, int nHeight, int nPosX, int nPosY)
{
    for (int i = nPosX; i < nWidth + nPosX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = nPosY; j < nHeight + nPosY; j++)
        {
            if (i == nPosX)
            {
                if (j == nPosY)
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'╔';
                }
                else if (j == nHeight + nPosY - 1)
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'╚';
                }
                else
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'║';
                }
            }
            else if (i == nWidth + nPosX - 1)
            {
                if (j == nPosY)
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'╗';
                }
                else if (j == nHeight + nPosY - 1)
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'╝';
                }
                else
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'║';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (j == nPosY || j == nHeight + nPosY - 1)
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L'═';
                }
                else
                {
                    wcBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L' ';
                }

            }
        }
    }

    int CapIndex = nPosY * nScreenWidth + (nPosX + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < wsCaption.length(); i++, CapIndex++)
    {
        wcBuffer[CapIndex] = wsCaption.at(i);
    }
}

void Block(wchar_t*& pBuffer, WORD*& pColor, int nTetromino, int nPosX, int nPosY)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (tetromino.at(nTetromino).at(0).at(j * 8 + i) != L'.')
            {
                pBuffer[(nPosY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nPosX + i)] = L'▓';
            }
            else
            {
                pBuffer[(nPosY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nPosX + i)] = L' ';
            }
            pColor[(nPosY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nPosX + i)] = 8 * 16 + nTetromino;
        }
    }
}

void Text(wchar_t*& pBuffer, wstring content, int nPosX, int nPosY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++, nPosX++)
    {
        pBuffer[nPosY * nScreenWidth + nPosX] = content.at(i);
    }
}

bool CheckPiece(int*& pMatrix, int nTetromino, int nRotation, int nPosX, int nPosY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (nPosX + i >= 0 && nPosX + i < nBoardWidth)
            {
                if (nPosY + j >= 0 && nPosY + j < nBoardHeight)
                {
                    if (tetromino.at(nTetromino).at(nRotation).at(j * 8 + i) != L'.' && pMatrix[(nPosY + j) * nBoardWidth + (nPosX + i)] != 0)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    Configure();

    WORD* pColor = new WORD[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
    wchar_t* pBuffer = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nScreenHeight; j++)
        {
            pBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = L' ';
            if (i == 0 || i >= nBoardWidth - 1 || j == nBoardHeight - 1)
            {
                pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = 8 * 16 + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                if (j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if (i % 4 == 1 || i % 4 == 2)
                    {
                        pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = 8 * 16 + 9;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = 7 * 16 + 9;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i % 4 == 3 || i % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = 8 * 16 + 9;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = 7 * 16 + 9;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int* pMatrix = new int[nBoardWidth * nBoardHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < nBoardWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nBoardHeight; j++)
        {
            if (j == nBoardHeight - 1)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i] = 4;
                }
                else if (i == nBoardWidth - 1)
                {
                    pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i] = 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i] = 7;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == nBoardWidth - 1)
                {
                    pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i] = 6;
                }
                else
                {
                    pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    Frame(pBuffer, L"[ SCORE ]", 17, 3, nBoardWidth, 1);
    Frame(pBuffer, L"[ LINE ]", 17, 3, nBoardWidth, 4);
    Frame(pBuffer, L"[ NEXT ]", 17, 6, nBoardWidth, 7);

    const vector<char> key = { 'W', 'A', 'S', 'D' };
    bool bKey[4];

    int nCurrentPiece = random(0, 6);
    int nNextPiece = random(0, 6);
    int nCurrentRotation = 0;
    int nCurrentX = nBoardWidth / 2 - 4;
    int nCurrentY = 0;
    
    int nFrame = 10;
    int nFrameCount = 0;
    bool bForceDown = 0;
    
    bool bRotateHold = 1;

    int nScore = 0;
    int nScorePosX = 37;
    int nScoreComp = 10;

    int nLine = 0;
    int nLinePosX = 37;
    int nLineComp = 10;

    vector<int> vLines;
    bool bGameOver = 0;

    while (bGameOver != 1)
    {
        // GAME TIMING
        Sleep(75);
        nFrameCount++;
        if (nFrameCount == nFrame)
        {
            bForceDown = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            bForceDown = 0;
        }

        // INPUT
        for (int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((GetKeyState(key.at(i)) & 0x8000) != 0)
            {
                bKey[i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                bKey[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        // GAME LOGIC
        int nLimit = 0;
        if (nCurrentPiece == 3)
        {
            nLimit = -1;
        }

        if (bKey[3] == 1 && nCurrentY >= nLimit)
        {
            if (CheckPiece(pMatrix, nCurrentPiece, nCurrentRotation, nCurrentX + 2, nCurrentY) == 1)
            {
                nCurrentX += 2;
            }

        }

        if (bKey[1] == 1 && nCurrentY >= nLimit && CheckPiece(pMatrix, nCurrentPiece, nCurrentRotation, nCurrentX - 2, nCurrentY) == 1)
        {
            nCurrentX -= 2;
        }

        if (bKey[2] == 1 && nCurrentY >= nLimit)
        {
            int i{};
            while (CheckPiece(pMatrix, nCurrentPiece, nCurrentRotation, nCurrentX, nCurrentY + i) == 1)
            {
                i++;
            }
            nCurrentY += i - 1;
        }

        if (bKey[0] == 1 && nCurrentY >= nLimit && bRotateHold == 1 && CheckPiece(pMatrix, nCurrentPiece, (nCurrentRotation + 1) % 4, nCurrentX, nCurrentY) == 1)
        {
            nCurrentRotation++;
            nCurrentRotation %= 4;
            bRotateHold = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            bRotateHold = 1;
        }

        if (bForceDown == 1)
        {
            nFrameCount = 0;

            if (CheckPiece(pMatrix, nCurrentPiece, nCurrentRotation, nCurrentX, nCurrentY + 1))
            {
                nCurrentY++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (nCurrentY < nLimit)
                {
                    bGameOver = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                        {
                            if (nCurrentY >= 0 && tetromino.at(nCurrentPiece).at(nCurrentRotation).at(j * 8 + i) != L'.')
                            {
                                pMatrix[(nCurrentY + j) * nBoardWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 2;
                                if ((nCurrentY + j) % 2 == 1)
                                {
                                    if ((nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 1 || (nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 2)
                                    {
                                        pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 8 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 7 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if ((nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 3 || (nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 0)
                                    {
                                        pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 8 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 7 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    {
                        if (nCurrentY + j < nBoardHeight - 1)
                        {
                            bool bLine = 1;
                            for (int i = 1; i < nBoardWidth - 1; i++)
                            {
                                if (pMatrix[(nCurrentY + j) * nBoardWidth + i] == 0)
                                {
                                    bLine = 0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (bLine == 1)
                            {
                                nLine++;

                                for (int i = 1; i < nBoardWidth - 1; i++)
                                {
                                    pMatrix[(nCurrentY + j) * nBoardWidth + i] = 3;
                                }
                                vLines.push_back(nCurrentY + j);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    nScore += 25;
                    if (!vLines.empty())
                    {
                        nScore += (1 << vLines.size()) * 100;
                    }

                    nCurrentX = nBoardWidth / 2 - 4;
                    nCurrentY = -4;
                    nCurrentRotation = 0;
                    nCurrentPiece = nNextPiece;
                    nNextPiece = random(0, 6);
                }
            }
        }

        // DISPLAY
        for (int i = 0; i < nBoardWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nBoardHeight; j++)
            {
                pBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i] = detail[pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i]];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if (tetromino.at(nCurrentPiece).at(nCurrentRotation).at(j * 8 + i) != L'.' && nCurrentY + j >= 0)
                {
                    if ((nCurrentY + j) % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        if ((nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 1 || (nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 2)
                        {
                            pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 8 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 7 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 3 || (nCurrentX + i) % 4 == 0)
                        {
                            pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 8 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pColor[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = 7 * 16 + nCurrentPiece;
                        }
                    }
                    pBuffer[(nCurrentY + j) * nScreenWidth + (nCurrentX + i)] = L'▓';
                }
            }
        }

        Block(pBuffer, pColor, nNextPiece, 26, 8);

        if (nScore >= nScoreComp)
        {
            nScorePosX--;
            nScoreComp *= 10;
        }
            
        Text(pBuffer, to_wstring(nScore), nScorePosX, 2);

        if (nLine >= nLineComp)
        {
            nLinePosX--;
            nLineComp *= 10;
        }
            
        Text(pBuffer, to_wstring(nLine), nLinePosX, 5);

        if (!vLines.empty())
        {
            WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, pBuffer, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
            Sleep(400);

            for (int l = 0; l < vLines.size(); l++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < nBoardWidth - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = vLines.at(l); j > 0; j--)
                    {
                        if (j % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            if (i % 4 == 1 || i % 4 == 2)
                            {
                                pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = pColor[(j - 1) * nScreenWidth + i] - 16;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = pColor[(j - 1) * nScreenWidth + i] + 16;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i % 4 == 1 || i % 4 == 2)
                            {
                                pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = pColor[(j - 1) * nScreenWidth + i] + 16;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i] = pColor[(j - 1) * nScreenWidth + i] - 16;
                            }
                        }
                        pMatrix[j * nBoardWidth + i] = pMatrix[(j - 1) * nBoardWidth + i];
                    }
                    pMatrix[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            vLines.clear();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nScreenHeight; j++)
            {
                COORD cPos;
                cPos.X = i;
                cPos.Y = j;
                WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, &pColor[j * nScreenWidth + i], 1, cPos, &dwBytesWritten);
            }
        }
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, pBuffer, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }

    CloseHandle(hConsole);

    cout << "Game Over !" << "\n";
    cout << "Score: " << nScore << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I use Visual Studio Code, there are no errors when checking it but when I run:

```
.\test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\test.cpp:550:42: error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, pBuffer, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
                                          ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from .\test.cpp:5:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:220:87: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'WINBOOL WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(HANDLE, LPCSTR, DWORD, COORD, LPDWORD)'
   WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(HANDLE hConsoleOutput,LPCSTR lpCharacter,DWORD nLength,COORD dwWriteCoord,LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten);
                                                                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
.\test.cpp:599:41: error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}
   WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, pBuffer, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
                                         ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from .\test.cpp:5:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:220:87: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'WINBOOL WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(HANDLE, LPCSTR, DWORD, COORD, LPDWORD)'
   WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(HANDLE hConsoleOutput,LPCSTR lpCharacter,DWORD nLength,COORD dwWriteCoord,LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten);
                                                                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like there is some errors related to MinGW. I have been checking some topics connected to this error and maybe UNICODE is related to this. Normally I found that most people use the old MinGW 2017 which doesn't have any major changes compare to this version. The UNICODE I use is UTF-8 in file properties and the PATH of system, the directory of G++/GCC have no problem.
SInce I'm kinda new to coding and mechanics behind these system so any explaination and solution to this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert wchar\_t to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019977/convert-wchar-t-to-char)

Comment: Sadly no. Any attempts to change wchar_t cause errors

Comment: what kind of errors? Have you tried [std::wcstombs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs) ?

Comment: Never tried that. How to use it in this case?

Comment: check the docu, everything u need is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i see that pBuffer have some issues and thats propably becasue you are using multibyte character set i compiled this code with multibyte character set and i get same errors like you  need to change multibyte character set to Use Unicode Character Set and it should solve your problem. Its viusal studio option :)

Comment: I didn't find that option, so how to change that?

Comment: properties -> advanced ->character set  .  Its for visual studio 2019

Comment: A better option, since the code is using `wchar_t` data and not `TCHAR` data, is to just use `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW()` directly instead of using `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()`, then the project's character set won't matter, since that only applies to `TCHAR` and related APIs. `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()` is a macro that is subject to what `TCHAR` maps to (`char` or `wchar_t`).

Comment: Have tried both of the ideas, all work, but Remy Lebeau solution is a better one. Thanks!